# Sudoku Recursive Backtrack Aid in C

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, sudoku

I am relatively new to coding and recursion has been a thorn in my side. I need help with implementing backtrack recursion.

Here is my sample code (Assume all helper functions work correctly [and they do])

```
void solve_sudoku(char sudoku[9][9])
{
    if (contains_empty_cell(sudoku) == 1)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
            {
                if (sudoku[y][x] == 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                    {
                        sudoku[y][x] = i;
                        if (is_valid_column(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                            is_valid_row(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                            is_valid_sub_box(sudoku, y, x) == 1)
                        {
                            solve_sudoku(sudoku);
                        }
                    }
                    if (sudoku[y][x] == 9)
                    {
                        sudoku[y][x] = 0;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I am trying to implement recursion and the code I have written was meant to solve the sudoku using the recursive backtrack method. However, it does not work. I need help understanding why so that I can fix it. Also suggestions on how to fix it would be welcomed.

Comment: We don't know what you mean by "it doesn't work". Can you show us the code you're using to test the function, and show the output and why it's wrong?

Comment: You have not detected when it reaches the end of the grid. At that point, a valid sudoku will be solved. But if this brute-force solution "doesn't work" it may be that it will solve it some time next year (or next decade).

Comment: @David G. All right sir, my mistake.

Comment: @ Weather Vane Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I think you are close. The main problem is how you are handling a solution. It seems you tried to handle it with `if (sudoku[y][x] == 9)`. But that's not correct.

Option 1 is to exit once a solution is found. `solve_sudoku()` returns a value to indicate so. The solution will be the end result after the outermost call of `solve_sudoku()`:

```c
int solve_sudoku(char sudoku[9][9])
{
    if (contains_empty_cell(sudoku) != 0)
    {
        return 1; // sudoku completely filled in, i.e. solution found
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            if (sudoku[y][x] == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                    sudoku[y][x] = i;
                    if (is_valid_column(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                        is_valid_row(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                        is_valid_sub_box(sudoku, y, x) == 1)
                    {
                        if (solve_sudoku(sudoku) == 1)
                        {
                            return 1; // exit if solution found
                        }
                    }
                }
                // restore empty cell
                sudoku[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A Sudoku can have multiple solutions. So option 2 is to print each found solution and then continue:

```c
void solve_sudoku(char sudoku[9][9])
{
    if (contains_empty_cell(sudoku) == 0)
    {
        // Sudoku completely filled in, print solution
        print_solution(sudoku);
        return;
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)
        {
            if (sudoku[y][x] == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
                {
                    sudoku[y][x] = i;
                    if (is_valid_column(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                        is_valid_row(sudoku, y, x) == 1 &&
                        is_valid_sub_box(sudoku, y, x) == 1)
                    {
                        solve_sudoku(sudoku);
                    }
                    
                }

                // restore empty cell
                sudoku[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it. So it might not be a complete solution.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it